# PDF Writer gem does not support special characters

Tags: ruby

Why the pdf writer does not support the special characters and russian,chinese letters using ruby

Comment: The [pdf-writer](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-writer) gem hasn't been updated since 2008. You might want to try a more recent gem instead, e.g. [prawn](https://rubygems.org/gems/prawn).

Answer (score 0):

It true that `pdf writer` does not `UTF-8` but you can implement you solution like following

**Overriding PDF::Writer text method**

Put the following code in a file called pdfwriter_extensions.rb (or whatever you choose to call it) in your lib directory:

```
CONVERTER = Iconv.new( 'ISO-8859-15//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', 'utf-8')

module PDF
    class Writer
        alias_method :old_text, :text

        def text(textto, options = {})
            old_text(CONVERTER.iconv(textto), options)
        end

    end
end
```

In your controller that handles the PDF output you add:

```
require 'pdf/writer'
require 'pdfwriter_extensions'
```

after which you can use PDF::Writer like in the tutorial:

```
pdf = PDF::Writer.new
pdf.select_font "Helvetica", :encoding => nil
pdf.text "User name: <b>#{@user.name}</b>", :font_size => 16, :justification => :left
send_data pdf.render, :disposition => 'inline', :filename => "user_details.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
```

N.B: I have taken this solution from https://www.peterkrantz.com/2007/utf8-in-pdf-writer/

Comment: ISO-8859-15 can neither handle Cyrillic nor Chinese characters. The result would be an empty string.

Comment: The tutorial mentions this limitation, too: _"... easy to solve as long as you only use Latin characters with diacritics"_